# Delete only works on the child not the parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a crud cart, the problem is in the delete, when I try do delete an item only deletes the
`<img onclick="deleteItemCart()" class="menu-thrash-save" src="img/thrash-can.jfif" width=15 alt="Thrash"></img>';`
and not the parent
`'<div id="bets-remove" class="cart-left-row">'`.

The 3 console.log and error are at the bottom

```
const addToCart = function () {
  getDescription('games.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err === null) {
      console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
    } else {
      var cartBets = document.getElementById('cart-bets');
      if (firstClickCart === 0) {
        cartBets.innerHTML = '';
        firstClickCart = 1;
      }
      cartBets.innerHTML += '<div id="bets-remove" class="cart-left-row">';
      cartBets.innerHTML += '<div class="bar-side-cart">';
      cartBets.innerHTML +=
        '<img onclick="deleteItemCart()" class="menu-thrash-save" src="img/thrash-can.jfif" width=15 alt="Thrash"></img>';
      cartBets.innerHTML +=
        '<p class="cart-right-text">01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 15, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25</p>';
      cartBets.innerHTML += '<div class="bets-info-right">';
      cartBets.innerHTML += '<div class="bets-info-megasena">Mega-Sena</div>';
      cartBets.innerHTML += '<div>R$ 4,50</div>';
      cartBets.innerHTML += '</div>';
    }
  });
};

function deleteItemCart() {
  var deleteFather = document.getElementById('bets-remove');
  var targetDelete = this.event.target;
  console.log(deleteFather);
  console.log(targetDelete);
  console.log(deleteFather.parentNode.removeChild(targetDelete));
  deleteFather.parentNode.removeChild(targetDelete);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should (also) post errors in code blocks, not as screenshots.

Comment: isn't it deleting it in the console log line itself? therefore it's no longer there to be deleted on the next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a function with `onclick="deleteItemCart()"`, `this` is not set automatically in the function. It's using the global context, so `this == window`, not the element that was cllicked.

You should pass `this` explicitly.

You can't use `document.getElementById('bets-remove')` to get the parent node. You're creating multiple elements with this ID, which is not valid; `deleteFather` will always be set to the first of them, not the parent of the item you clicked on. But you don't need to get the father; you can use `.remove()` to remove an element explicitly.

But `targetDelete` isn't the element you want to remove, it's just the image.
Use `.closest()` to find the containing DIV for the entire cart item.

Another problem is the way you're adding the item to the cart. Whenever you assign to `.innerHTML` it reparses all the HTML to create valid DOM. You can't create nested elements by successive concatenations, because it automatically closes any unclosed elements. Instead, do all the concatenation into a string, then assign that to `innerHTML` at once.

```js
const addToCart = function () {
  getDescription('games.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err === null) {
      console.log('Ocorreu um erro' + err);
    } else {
      var cartBets = document.getElementById('cart-bets');
      if (firstClickCart === 0) {
        cartBets.innerHTML = '';
        firstClickCart = 1;
      }
      let html = '';
      html += '<div id="bets-remove" class="cart-left-row">';
      html += '<div class="bar-side-cart">';
      html +=
        '<img onclick="deleteItemCart()" class="menu-thrash-save" src="img/thrash-can.jfif" width=15 alt="Thrash"></img>';
      html +=
        '<p class="cart-right-text">01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 15, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25</p>';
      html += '<div class="bets-info-right">';
      html += '<div class="bets-info-megasena">Mega-Sena</div>';
      html += '<div>R$ 4,50</div>';
      html += '</div></div></div>';
      cartBets.innerHTML += html;
    }
  });
};

function deleteItemCart(targetDelete) {
  console.log(targetDelete);
  let item = targetDelete.closest(".cart-left-row");
  item.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just have to put  item.remove(targetDelete);

Comment: `item.remove()` doesn't take an argument. It just removes `item`, which includes all its contents.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML looks something like this:

```html
<div id="bets-remove" class="cart-left-row">
    <div class="bar-side-cart">
        <img onclick="deleteItemCart()" class="menu-thrash-save" src="img/thrash-can.jfif" width=15 alt="Thrash"></img>
        <p class="cart-right-text">01, 02, 04, 05, 06, 07, 09, 15, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25</p>
        <div class="bets-info-right">
            <div class="bets-info-megasena">Mega-Sena</div>
            <div>R$ 4,50</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*your HTML is missing two `</div>`s it seems.*

I'm not sure whether it's safe to perform multiple `cartBets.innerHTML +=` operations. I think e.g. Chromium-based browsers would "auto-correct" the HTML for e.g. missing closing tags.

As for your actual problem, your `onclick` has `event.target` pointing at the `<img>` tag, yet your `deleteFather` is the top `<div id="bets-remove" class="cart-left-row">`. You need to delete the `img` tag from `<div class="bar-side-cart">` instead.

Of course, it might be better to switch over to a framework such as React, instead of using raw HTML and such.